What justifies the $log$ in $Kt$ complexity ? (Variants of $Kt$ complexity with other bounds)
Recall $Kt$ complexity and its lesser known brother $KT$ complexity. Call $x\in \{0;1\}^\ast$ a string we have the following definitions :
$Kt(x) = \min \{ |p| + log(t) \quad ; \text{ program p outputs $x$ in $t$ steps} \}$
$KT(x) = \min \{ |p| + t \quad ; \text{ program p outputs $x$ in $t$ steps} \}$
Those are the only kinds of temporal Kolmogorov complexity I've ever come across in  the literature, I'm under the impression the temporal bounds are kind of arbitrary therefore I introduce the following notion $K^ft$ where $f$ is a function :
$K^ft(x) = \min \{ |p| + f(t) \quad ; \text{ program p outputs $x$ in $t$ steps} \}$
Recall the problem $MKtP$ (Minimum Kt problem) which where given $x$ you have to output $Kt(x)$. Some smart people care to know if $MKtP \in P$ (There's apparently a relativizing barrier against that but not much else is known) . My questions are the following :

Are there any special reasons why we only study $Kt$ complexity and not $K^ft$

Let's say hypothetically I could show $K^{g\log}t \not \in P$ for any $g=\omega(1)$, would you care ? (in the sense is it trivial). Note that $K^{g\log}t$ is almost the usual $Kt$ complexity hence why anyone would care.



FYI there is also time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity: K^t(x)=min{|p| : p outputs x in at most t(|x|) steps}. (And more generally resource-bounded, e.g. people have also looked at space-bounded.)

I edited the post, yes i am familiar with $K^t$

There are several questions that you pose.  Let's address each one in turn:

What justifies the log in Kt complexity?
I think that the best answer is that Levin showed that, if you want to find satisfying assignments to a formula $\phi$ with $n$ variables, then an essentially optimal approach is to search through all $n$-bit strings $x$ in order of increasing $Kt(x|\phi)$.
.

Are there any special reasons why we only study Kt complexity and not $K^ft$?
I myself have studied KT, which is $K^ft$ where $f=n$.  The reason that I am interested in KT is that KT(x) is related to the circuit size required to compute the function with truth table $x$.  If you find something interesting to say about $K^ft$ for other functions $f$, that will provide good motivation for studying it.

Would it be interesting to show $K^{g\log}t\not\in P$ for some $g =\omega(1)$?  Yes!  This would be very interesting.  For instance, if $g(n)=n/\log n$, then $K^{g\log}t$ is KT (which is computable in $P^{NP}$, and this would show P$\neq$ NP.  The consequences would not be nearly so dramatic for smaller functions $g$, but it would still be very interesting.  Really, it seems like it should be obvious that Kt is not computable in polynomial time, since Kt is hard for EXP (under P/poly reductions) ... but of course we are currently unable to prove this.  Showing $K^{g\log}t\not\in P$ for some $g =\omega(1)$ seems like it would be even harder to prove, although this implication doesn't seem obvious to me right now.


